# ASP.NET C# Binding Dotnet Highcharts to sql server database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project asp.net web app forms with sql database with a table I created as a sales table. Below is how my table design looks like

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales] (
        [Id]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Month] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
        [Sale]  INT          NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
```

On my sales.aspx page i added the following html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:Literal id="chrtMyChart" runat="server">
     </asp:Literal>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

On my sales.cs i coded the following

```
protected void Render_Chart()
        {

            // define the connection string
            string constring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString1"].ToString();

            // Declare the SQL connection

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(constring);

            // and add a query string for retrieving the data.

            string commandText = "select Sale from Sales";

            SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConn);

            // Open the connection
            myConn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(myComm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // and execute the query
            SqlDataReader reader = myComm.ExecuteReader();

            Object[] chartValues = new Object[12]; // declare an object for the chart rendering  
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // GetValue() returns the data row from the query
                    // So:
                    //       GetValue(0) will contain the month number [<em>month(eaten_Pizza) as Mese</em>]
                    //       GetValue(1) will contain the number of eaten pizzas [<em>count(eaten_Pizza)</em>]



                    chartValues[(Int32)reader.GetValue(0) - 1] = reader.GetValue(1);


                    // minus 1 because the array starts from 0, whenever the months start from 1
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }

            reader.Close(); // close the reader

            // Declare the HighCharts object    
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
                .SetTitle(new Title
                {
                    Text = "Monthly Number of Pizza",
                    X = -20
                })
                .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle
                {
                    Text = "Source: Pizza Connect db",
                    X = -20
                })
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                {
                    Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
                })
                .SetSeries(new[]
                        {
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "# Pizza",
                    Data = new Data(chartValues)   // Here we put the dbase data into the chart                   
                },
                    });


            chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString(); // Let's visualize the chart into the webform.

        }
```

This is my sales table info
[Sales table Data in Sql severs Visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PSZ4.png)

I then call `Render_Chart();` on the page load of sales.cs.When i run my project i get the following error

```
An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

It indicate this line with a run time error

```
chartValues[(Int32)reader.GetValue(0) - 1] = reader.GetValue(1);
```

So how should i do with this line to resolve the issue so that it can load my values on my Y axis? Please help me..i will appreciate.

Comment: Check you sql command - you're selecting only one field "Sale" from table, but later you're doing "reader.GetValue(1);" , which indicates that your selection sould contain at least 2 fields. Try to use "select Month, Sale from Sales"

Comment: Sorry...it does not help anymore it gives this error still                           An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException means that you are trying to access element in array, but it's index less than 0 or more than array.length. You should underastand which operator causes this error. Try to split your chartValues[(Int32)reader.GetValue(0) - 1] = reader.GetValue(1); into separate operators: object indx = reader.GetValue(0); object value = reader.GetValue(1); int index = Int32.Parse(indx); chartValues[index] = value;  - this will helps you to find out where the problem hides.